# JavaScript import favicon.ico

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-boilerplate

I met this string of code:

```
import '!file-loader?name=[name].[ext]!./images/favicon.ico';
```

[here](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/blob/master/app/app.js).

Please, explain me, how this construction works, in details, if possible, or help to get an info about it

Comment: That's an [inline Webpack loader](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/#inline). The `name` parameter seems redundant to me since it would name the imported icon to `favicon` `.` `ico`, which is the name of the icon, so it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Thank you! But how square brackets work here is still unclear to me...

Comment: You're welcome! It's the way Webpack knows where to input certain data. `[name]` will be replaced with the filename, `[ext]` will be replaced with the file extension, and e.g. `[chunkhash]` will be replaced by a unique hash for the particular file. You could try `[name].[chunkhash].[ext]` as an experiment to see what it does.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an [inline Webpack loader](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/#inline). The `name` parameter seems redundant to me since it would name the imported icon to `favicon` `.` `ico`, which is the name of the icon, so it doesn't change anything.

The square bracket notation is the way Webpack knows where to input certain data. `[name]` will be replaced with the filename, `[ext]` will be replaced with the file extension, and e.g. `[chunkhash]` will be replaced by a unique hash for the particular file. You could try `[name].[chunkhash].[ext]` as an experiment to see what it does.